# Why Isn't This Query Caching When Using PHPFastCache?

Tags: php, mysql, caching

I am trying to cache a query on a page using http://www.phpfastcache.com/.

I am getting no errors on the page, and the files are being created successfully in the cached.storage folder that it needs, but when I change data in a query, it is not caching the data. What am I doing wrong?

```
include_once("php_fast_cache.php");
phpFastCache::$storage = "auto";

$getItemsQuery = phpFastCache::get("$itemId");
if($getItemsQuery == null) {
    $getItemsQuery = mysql_query("select item_id, item_name from items where item_id = $itemId");
    phpFastCache::set("$itemId", $getItemsQuery,86400);
}
```

Comment: PLease elaborate, exactly what you mean by 'when I change data in a query'

Comment: Please read up on [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) to avoid severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Also, `mysql_query` should not be used in new applications. It's a deprecated interface that's being removed from future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) will help you avoid making mistakes like this.

Comment: @barryhunter I mean I am just changing data in a table record to test if the caching is working correctly.

Comment: @tadman Thanks for the response. I do use SQL escaping, but just simplified it for the example.

Comment: So you say you change the data in the database, but you DO or you DON'T see the change on the page. Because of the caching it would be EXPECTED to not see the change. Unless you also purge the cache.

Comment: Sorry, should have specified. I AM seeing the changes on the page. Whereas I would hope to not see the changes if the caching was working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, right you should be caching the actual 'data' in the cache, ie the **data** you get back from mysql_fetch_assoc etc.

Trying to cache the 'resource' you get back from running the query wont help, because the next instance that calls 'get' wont be able to use the resource (even if it is cached - which I doubt)

... you see no error, because the 'get' fails, so just runs the mysql query.

Can ignore the issue with using mysql extension here. using mysqli or PDO etc would have exactly the same issue used in this way.